# Method for detecting circles in a background similar to the circle image processing

Tags: opencv, c++11, image-processing

So to give a context to the problem we are trying to detect wheels of a vehicle whose image is obtained using a thermal camera .... Now many times due to rain or other causes the wheel cools down an it is quite similar to road .... for eg.

[image]

Here you can see very clearly that the wheel is quite similar to the background. So are there any features or image processing techniques that can be used to identify the dim wheel or differentiate it from its background.

Comment: did you try adaptive threshold ?

Comment: No, thank you for the suggestion ... its a brilliant suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try CLAHE.  I have written following code snippet. Check if this is helpful to you

```
cv::Mat in_gray;
cvtColor(input, in_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);  //input is your image

Ptr<CLAHE> clahe = createCLAHE();
clahe->setClipLimit(12);

Mat in_clahe;
clahe->apply(in_gray, in_clahe);
```

Following is the results of this on your image:

[image: output]

Comment: Try to change clipLimit value. Or you can try gamma correction or histogram equalisation technique.